# Convert Func<object, Task> to Func<T, Task> at runtime

Tags: c#, reflection

I have a `Func<object, Task>`. I am trying to pass it as an argument into a function that takes `Func<T, Task>`. I am using reflection to create a `MethodInfo` for the function, and the `T` being filled in is not known until runtime.

How can I do this with reflection?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You *don't* need to do anything special.

[`Func<in T, out TResult>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549151.aspx) is [*contravariant*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd799517.aspx) on `T` - its input parameter, and every type inherits from `object`, which means you can just *cast* `Func<object, Task>` to `Func<T, Task>` for *any reference type* `T` - pass it as-is and it will just work.

[Example](http://ideone.com/pbYvUu)

Now, this won't work for value types, since those require *unboxing* beforehand.

So if your `T` is a value type, you'll have to wrap it in another delegate which will perform a cast.

One simple way would be to define a wrapper method:

```
private static Func<T, TResult> CastFunc<T, TResult>(Func<object, TResult> fn)
    => param => fn(param);
```

Then create a delegate through reflection:

```
var result = (Func<int, Task>)typeof(WrapperClass)
    .GetMethod(nameof(CastFunc), BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static)
    .MakeGenericMethod(typeof(int), typeof(Task)).Invoke(null, new object[] { fn });
```

Comment: Doh. I completely missed that.

Answer (score 1):

I'd go for reflection using `MakeGenericMethod`

Here's a quick example:

```
    public class Example
    {
        public void Start()
        {
             Func<object, Task> func = o => null;
             object objFunc = func; // got it from a generic place as an object or something
             Type type = objFunc.GetType().GetGenericArguments()[0]; // get T in runtime
             var method = typeof(Example).GetMethod("DoSomething", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance).MakeGenericMethod(type);
             var result = method.Invoke(this, new object[1] { func });
        }

        public int DoSomething<T>(Func<T, Task> input)
        {
            return 1;
        }
    }
```